# LINQ to SQL query to determine if value starts with numeric

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a project where I query users by first letter:

```
repository.GetAll().Where(q => q.BrukerIdent.StartsWith(letter.ToString())).ToList();
```

..where `repository.GetAll()` returns an `IQueryable<Bruker>`, `BrukerIdent` is a string that contains the username, and `letter` is a char-value coming in. This works perfectly, except that I also want to get users that starts with digits. And I don't want to sort by separate digits.

My mind yells for a `StartsWith("\d")` but as far as I have found out it doesn't work this way. I have also thought of doing a 10-way OR clause, but that would look like spaghetti, and I'm not sure of the efficiency.

Is there any "right" way to do it like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
repository.GetAll().Where(q => Char.IsNumber(q.BrukerIdent[0]))
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y.aspx)

---

```
var numbers = Enumerable
                     .Range(0, 10)
                     .Select(i => i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

// var numbers = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 );
// var numbers = HashSet<int> { ... };

var q = from b in repository.GetAll()
        where numbers.Contains(b.BrukerIdent.FirstOrDefault())) //[0]
        select b;
```

Comment: No it doesn't. `Boolean IsDigit(Char) has no supported translation to SQL` :/

Comment: @Marc: Probably, I'm not sure. Maybe my updated my answer will work?

Comment: I didn't think about using contains that way. I rewrote it a bit (turning the string "0123456789" to a chararray), but it worked like that. Giving it to you :)

Comment: @Christian: Try also `new HashSet<int>("..".ToCharArray())`, it should give you the best performance.

Comment: the hashset approach should be no faster than your array based one, and perhaps a *miniscule* amount slower; don't forget that LINQ-to-SQL has to flatten it to parameters anyway.

Comment: Or you colud write a UDF in TSQL called IsNumeric and include that in your dbml file

Comment: This assumes that BrukerIdent has at least one character.

Comment: @Joe: Such check can be implemented easily. All the more `WHERE NULL IN (1,2,3)` should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: BrukerIdent is not nullable. (Bruker = User in Norwegian)

Comment: @abatishchev - FirstOrDefault is a good one, works because a string is an IEnumerable<char>.  But then your numbers should be defined as char rather than string, i.e. "numbers = Enumerable.Range('0' , 10)"

Answer (score 14):

If this is for LINQ-to-SQL you could use [`SqlMethods.Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx) method here:

```
var result = repository
    .GetAll()
    .Where(q => SqlMethods.Like(q.BrukerIdent, "[0-9]%"))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: +1. The title of the question specifies LINQ to SQL - this answer is LINQ to SQL - i.e. the filtering will be done on the DB server.  I believe the accepted answer from @abatishchev will use LINQ to Objects (filtering on the client), as will the sample in the original question.

Comment: Note that you may need to add a reference to "System.Data.Linq" to your porject, then add the namespace "System.Data.Linq.SqlClient" in your class, otherwise you'll get an error that "SqlMethods" is not found.

Answer (score 2):

I *suspect* @abatishchev's revised answer will help here, but if you are doing this lots, or this is an important query, then I strongly suggest a refactor. For example:

```
create table Test (
    id int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    name nvarchar(20) not null,
    firstChar as (case when LEN(name) = 0 then null
            else SUBSTRING(name,1,1) end) persisted
    )
go
create nonclustered index Test_firstChar on Test (firstChar)
```

I can now do a very efficient first-character match simply by testing `firstChar`. Which could be an integer instead if the numeric ones are particularly important.

Comment: It's only for managing users in a superuser interface. So it doesn't need to be überefficient ;)

Comment: @Marc - is the Substring only available for tsql? For some reason my linq queries are doing a like when I want something similar to this...

Comment: @Haroon like is fine for testing matches

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not so readable, but the following would probably work:

```
q.BrukerIdent >= "0" && q.BrukerIdent < ":"
```

Maybe there are some exotic collation sequences where this would fail, but I expect it would work in most situations.