# Subsonic query to determine if value starts with numeric

Tags: c#, .net, linq, subsonic

*This is a follow-up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702168/linq-to-sql-query-to-determine-if-value-starts-with-numeric) question, however the context has changed. Breaking the accepted solution.*

*This time I'm trying to use SubSonic, but it throws an errormessage using the previous accepted solution*

```
System.NotSupportedException: The method 'get_Chars' is not supported
...
Line 36:             char[] nums = "0123456789".ToCharArray();
Line 37: 
Line 38:             var b = repository.GetAll().Where(q => nums.Contains(q.BrukerIdent[0])).ToList();
Line 39: 
Line 40:
```

As far as I can tell `q.BrukerIdent` is a string. So I'm a bit thrown...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget LINQ - Don't use it.  There is a better way to accomplish your goal.  Use SQL.  You'd be **done already** if you would've just used SQL - it's just a [basic pattern search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

Subsonic?  Use a `CodingHorror` and use the appropriate SQL.

`CodingHorror` is a class that is in the SubSonic assembly.  It gives you a way to execute specific, hand-written SQL for instances where **trying to achieve the same result with LINQ would be difficult if not impossible, and therefore a complete waste of time**.

You can also execute a `CodingHorror` query and ask it to give you the results as a list of your strongly-typed objects.

Here's a use of CodingHorror that should solve your problem, but you'll have to fill in a couple of the particulars (table name, type name).

```
var query = new CodingHorror(@"SELECT * FROM YourTableHere 
                               WHERE BrukerIdent LIKE '[a-z0-9]%'");
var matchingItems = query.ExecuteTypedList<YourTypeHere>();
```

Also, there's been a bit of an exodus from using SubSonic, and even larger ORM's in general.  I recommend looking at [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) (or Massive or Dapper, etc.).  The author of PetaPoco was driven by his experience of having to use `CodingHorror` far too often in projects that utilized SubSonic.

Comment: Two downvotes, really?  Maybe I'll just delete this since it's apparently so unhelpful.

Comment: I changed to an upvote. Your original answer came off really snarky.

Comment: @rossisdead: ya, I'm feeling snarky today. Thanks for egging me into making it better.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Substring` instead of the character indexer?

```
string[] nums = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0" };
var b = repository.GetAll().Where(q => nums.Contains(q.BrukerIdent.Substring(0, 1))).ToList()
```

Note I had to make `nums` a string[] instead of a char[] since Substring() returns a string not a char.

Incase that still has a problem running, sometimes SubSonic likes for the object that `.Contains()` is being called on to be an IEnumerable instead, so you might have to do:

```
var nums = (new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0" }).AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make it without using lambda functions and other stuff in order to see where the issue is ?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to convert the linq expression to a valid sql expression.

It seems to me, the method getChars (the indexer on `q.BrukerIdent`) is not supported in the IQueryableProvider you use.