# RegEx with LINQ to SQL queries to filter data to show on the UI

Tags: regex, linq-to-sql

Working with a database TABLE called Costcenter. 
I am trying to show the Costcenters in a dropdownlist where CostcenrCode is only three numeric characters. I was trying to do that on the VIEW on an ASP.Net WF application. Now I have moved it to the DataAccess query where I am using LINQ to SQL. I am bit confused, how to do it in the LINQ query where I am returning String. I am selecting cc at the end which is populating all the Costcenters in the database table. But I need to only pull the one is like (e.g. 100 instead of F.C56).

My DataAccess code is as follows:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Costcenter> GetAllCostcentersByCountryCompanyProfitcenterYear(short year, int companyID)
    {
        List<Costcenter> costcenters = new List<Costcenter>();
        using (var context = new CostReportEntities())
        {
            costcenters = (from cc in context.Costcenters
                           join company in context.Companies on cc.CompanyID equals company.CompanyID
                           where cc.Year == year && cc.CompanyID == companyID
                           select cc).ToList();

        }
        return costcenters;

    }
```

I have been looking at few posts here, but couldn't put anything together since I am new in LINQ to SQL.

Comment: You can't use Regex.IsMatch with linq to SQL.

Comment: What RDMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, ....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do the trick:

```
var costcenters = (from cc in context.Costcenters
                    join company in context.Companies on cc.CompanyID equals company.CompanyID
                    where cc.Year == year && cc.CompanyID == companyID &&
                       SqlMethods.Like(cc.CostcenrCode, "[0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%")
                    select cc).ToList();
```

Source:

[LINQ to SQL query to determine if value starts with numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5702473/558486)

Edit 1 - added alternative solution using `SqlMethods.PatIndex`:

```
var costcenters = (from cc in context.Costcenters
                    join company in context.Companies on cc.CompanyID equals company.CompanyID
                    where cc.Year == year && cc.CompanyID == companyID &&
                       SqlMethods.PatIndex("[0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%", cc.CostcenrCode) > 0
                    select cc).ToList();
```

Comment: This seems not gonna work for LINQ to Entities and gives the error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @shaz: I confess I didn't tested it, I thought it would be supported in Linq to Entities. try with SqlMethods.PatIndex, it may work. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient; and the Syntax SqlFunctions.PatIndex() your second suggestions worked. Although it's pulling up data with 4 digits too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Regex.Match`, but you need to *materialize* your data first. You said, this is the data for the dropdown list, so this solution may be acceptable:

```
costcenters =  (
        from cc in context.Costcenters
        join company in context.Companies on cc.CompanyID equals company.CompanyID
        where cc.Year == year && cc.CompanyID == companyID
        select cc
    ).AsEnumerable()
    .Where(cc => Regex.IsMatch(cc.CostcenrCode, @"^\d{3}$"))
    .ToList();
```

The trick here is in [`AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) method which enumerates your data, and you may apply regex methods on your data after this.

Comment: Not the best solution because it will load all data from the database and only then you can apply the regex.

Comment: @RuiJarimba: yes, I know. This solution is not for every scenario, of cause. But I think, it's more than acceptable for a dropdown list.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    ...
costcenters = (from cc in context.Costcenters
                    join company in context.Companies on cc.CompanyID equals company.CompanyID
                    where cc.Year == year && cc.CompanyID == companyID &&
                       Regex.IsMatch(cc.CostcenrCode, @"^\d{3}$");
                    select cc).ToList();
```

Comment: It shows an error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsMatch(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: You can't use Regex.IsMatch with Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities. It will work with Linq to Objects though

Comment: @RuiJarimba: would you happen to have any suggestion for the mentioned problem?