# counting Movie by grouping alphabetically using linq

Tags: c#, linq

What I have to do is count all the movies that start with a letter and number as number=20, A=10, B=12,......z=18 etc. I have so far tried two queries to achieve my desired result:

First:

```
var companyquery = (from movieInfo in db.MovieInformations
                     group movieInfo by movieInfo.MovieTitle.Substring(0, 1)
                            into movieInfogroup
                            select new MovieNumberModel
                            {
                                Character = movieInfogroup.Key,
                                Number = movieInfogroup.Count() 
                            }).OrderBy(mapping => mapping.Character);
```

but it grouped only by the first letter. So, I made another table that stores the alphabet and wrote the following linq query:

```
var companyquery1 = (from movieInfo in db.MovieInformations
                     from Category in db.CharCategory
                         group movieInfo.MovieTitle by Category.Character
                         into movieInfogroup
                         select new MovieNumberModel
                         {
                             Character = movieInfogroup.Key,
                             Number = movieInfogroup.Count() 
                         }).OrderBy(mapping => mapping.Character)
```

This linq query does give all the alphabet like A to z but does not count correctly. Please help me find the solution so that all the movies that start with a number go in one category, and the ones that start with a letter get grouped according to the alphabet. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of titles and groups you are trying to achieve? Like "27 Dresses" must be in which group? The "27" group?

Comment: 27 Dresses should be in group titled "number". And American Gangster should be in "A".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you group your result, you can test if the first caracter is a digit or not. If it is, group by a special name like "Number", else group by the first caracter:

```
var companyquery1 = db.MovieInformations
   .Select(movieInfo => movieInfo.MovieTitle.FirstOrDefault().ToString())
   .GroupBy(firstChar => SqlMethods.Like(firstChar, "[0-9]%") ? "Number" : firstChar)
   .Select(grp => new { Character = grp.Key, Number = grp.Count() })
   .OrderBy(anon => anon.Character);
```

You must use the `SqlMethods.Like` function, since you are querying the database.

You can also loads all the informations in memory for being able to use classic method:

```
var movieInformations = db.MovieInformations.ToList();
var companyquery1 = movieInformations 
   .Select(movieInfo => movieInfo.MovieTitle.FirstOrDefault().ToString())
   .GroupBy(firstChar => Char.IsDigit(firstChar) ? "Number" : firstChar)
   .Select(grp => new { Character = grp.Key, Number = grp.Count() })
   .OrderBy(anon => anon.Character);
```

The choice is up to you and the volume of your database/performance requierement.

Reference :

- [LINQ to SQL query to determine if value starts with numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5702473/128662)
- [SqlMethods.Like Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx)

Comment: IsDigit is not working for lambda expression. It says it could not be changed to store expression.

Comment: True, Char.IsDigit cannot be used in a Linq to Sql query. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you Scorpi0,Classical method worked fine for me as I am using linq to entity. I may have about 1 million movie Information. Does it give some performance issues?