# LINQ query for number match

Tags: sql, linq

I have a table named **dbo.Question** having two columns **Id** and **Title**. I want to write LINQ query to get all questions where the ***question Title begins with numbers***.

The following is a sample of question search result where the "Title" starts with a number:

- 5 Useful Visual Studio shortcuts
- 7 Things to know about Hadoop.
- 10 Reasons You Should Be Thankful For Hackers

The SQL query is like:

```
SELECT Title FROM dbo.Question WHERE Title NOT LIKE '[a-z]%'
```

What will be the LINQ equivalent of the above SQL query?

Comment: You find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702168/linq-to-sql-query-to-determine-if-value-starts-with-numeric

Comment: @PeterRing will not work with either Entity Framework nor Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = from x in dbcontext.Questions
            where SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(EntityFunctions.Left(x.Title, 1)) == 1
            select x;
```

Source:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.isnumeric(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383069(v=vs.110).aspx

Come to think of it, this isn't very efficient, given that it doesn't use indices. You can instead do this...

```
IEnumerable<string> digits  = Enumerable.Range(0, 10) // 0-9
                                 .Select(i => i.ToString());
                  //Create a query for starts with on each digit.
IEnumerable<IQueryable<Question>> questions = digits
            .Select(i => dbcontext.Questions.Where(q => q.StartsWith(i))
IQueryable<Question> concatedTogether = .Aggregate(Queryable.Concat) //Union all each of them together                      
int count = concatedTogether.Count();
```

OR simply

```
int count = Enumerable.Range(0, 9)
                .Select(int.ToString)
                .Select(i => dbcontext.Questions.Where(q => q.StartsWith(i))
                .Aggregate(Queryable.Concat)
                .Count();
```